# Rolling Dice Game, Probability of Ending on an Even Roll

Tags: probability-theory, dice

The game is described as follows. $A$ and $B$ take turns rolling a fair six sided die. Say $A$ rolls first. Then if $A$ rolls {1,2} they win. If not, then $B$ rolls. If $B$ rolls {3,4,5,6} then they win. This process repeats until $A$ or $B$ wins, and the game stops.

**What is the probability that the game ends on an even turn when $A$ rolls first?**

Now the book gives the answer as $\frac{4}{7}$, however, when try to calculate I end up with $\frac{2}{11}$.

**Below is my work:**

To calculate this probability, we decompose the event into two disjoint events, (a) the event where $A$ wins on an even roll, and (b) the event where $B$ wins on an even roll.

(a) Now, the probability $A$ wins can be calculated as follows
\begin{align*}
\biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{1}{3}\biggr) + \biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{1}{3}\biggr) + \dots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{2k+1}\frac{1}{3}\\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{27}\biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{27}\biggr(\frac{4}{81}\biggr)^k = \frac{2}{27}\cdot \frac{1}{1- \frac{4}{81}} = \frac{6}{77}.
\end{align*}

(b) Similarly we calculate the probability $B$ wins on an even roll as
\begin{align*}
\biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\biggr) + \biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\biggr) + \dots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{2k+1}\frac{4}{9}\\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8}{81}\biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8}{81}\biggr(\frac{4}{81}\biggr)^k = \frac{8}{81}\cdot \frac{1}{1- \frac{4}{81}} = \frac{8}{77}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, it follows that the probability of the game ending on an even number of rolls is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{6}{77} + \frac{8}{77} = \frac{2}{11}.
\end{equation*}

Am I missing something?

Comment: Unclear what the interpretation of rolling a set (e.g., $\{1, 2\}$) is.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting it as turn 1A, then turn 1B, then turn 2A, then turn 2B, then turn 3A, then turn 3B, etc...  Are you sure the problem doesn't intend for it to be instead turn 1 (A's turn), turn 2 (B's turn), turn 3 (A's second turn), turn 4 (B's second turn), turn 5 (A's third turn), etc...?

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading, but isn't the answer clearly $\frac 12$ by symmetry?  Why should it be more likely to end on an even toss than an odd one?

Comment: @lulu I interpret it not as the die result, but the turn number and turn number very clearly doesn't need to be symmetrical in a problem like this.  Consider the game with an unfair coin where heads occurs $99\%$ of the time and first to flip heads wins.  It will end on an odd turn most of the time (*because it ends specifically on the first turn most of the time*).  Looking at the OP's attempt, it is clear that their interpretation is the same as mine except they interpret it rather than "ends after an even number of combined rolls" as "ends after an even number of rolls by player A"

Comment: @JMoravitz  Maybe....but in that case, isn't that the same as asking that $B$ be the winner?  Though the OP explicitly considers the case in which $A$ wins...

Comment: @IanFromWashington  Can you clarify your question?  As you can see, there is some confusion.

Comment: Ah I see the problem within my attempt at the answer, thank you @JMoravitz, I was incorrectly interpreting the notion of turns and that's what stumped me. I'll write up the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @lulu, I meant even turn, I'll edit the original question to make that clear.

Comment: If the wording is as represented in the OP, and the interpretation is as OP indicates in their answer, this is a horribly worded question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @JMoravitz I realized my mistake. I was interpreting turns as the rolls $A$ AND $B$, as in $\{A_1,B_1\}, \{A_2,B_2\}, \dots$. In reality the question is merely asking what the probability of $B$ winning if $A$ rolls first.

**The work is as follows:**
We calculate the probability of $B$ winning. Denote the probability of $B$ winning on their $i$th roll as $S_i$. Now, the probabilities of $B$ winning on her first roll, second roll, third roll, etc., are as follows:
\begin{equation*}
 P(S_1) = \biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr), \quad P(S_2) = \biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr), \quad P(S_3) = \biggr(\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{1}{3}\biggr)\biggr)^2\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{2}{3}\biggr), \dots
\end{equation*}
It then follows that in general that $\displaystyle P(S_i) = \biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{i-1} \biggr(\frac{4}{9}\biggr).$ Thus, it follows that the probability of $B$ winning is calculated as
\begin{equation*}
 P(S) = P\biggr(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i\biggr) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(S_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{i-1} \biggr(\frac{4}{9}\biggr) = \frac{4}{9} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \biggr(\frac{2}{9}\biggr)^{i-1} = \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{9}{7} = \frac{4}{7}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: This question and experience overall should reinforce the importance of well written questions, not just from an asker's point of view on SE but in textbooks and tests as well.  Ambiguous language adds unnecessary difficulty.  In the end, knowing how to solve the problem for each possible interpretation and understanding the differences in possible interpretations is important as a student, and as a teacher/problemwriter being aware of said possible differences in interpretations and writing unambiguous questions is also important.  I don't think you're at fault here.

Comment: I was actually going to address this key learning from this experience for myself. This experience has further highlighted the importance of rigor and precision in language

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not clear as stated.

Interpretation $\#1$:  If you interpret it as "find the probability that the game end in an evenly numbered round" you can reason recursively.

Let $P$ denote the answer. The probability that the game ends in the first round is $\frac 26+\frac 46\times \frac 46=\frac 79$. If you don't end in the first round, the probability is now $1-P$.  Thus $$P=\frac 79\times 0 +\frac 29\times (1-P)\implies \boxed{P=\frac 2{11}}$$

as in your solution.

Interpretation $\#2$:  If the problem meant "find the probability that $B$ wins given that $A$ starts" that too can be solved recursively.  Let $\Psi$ denote that answer and let $\Phi$ be the probability that $B$ wins given that $B$ starts.  Then $$\Psi=\frac 46\times \Phi$$ and $$\Phi=\frac 46 +\frac 26\times \Psi$$  This system is easily solved and yields $$\boxed {\Psi=\frac 47}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Working under the assumption that the intended interpretation of the question was merely asking the probability that $B$ wins (*i.e. distinguishing between the term "rounds" as iterating whenever A has a turn and "turns" iterating whenever either A or B has a turn*) two other approaches have already been written.  Here I will include yet another approach:

Consider the final round, that is a roll of $A$ followed by a roll of $B$, where we allow $B$ to roll even in the event that $A$ has already won despite the roll not influencing the final result of the game.

Ordinarily there are $6\times 6 = 36$ equally likely results for a round.  Here, we condition on the fact that it is the *last* round, implying that it was not the case that both players missed their respective targets.  This gives $6\times 6 - 4\times 2 = 28$ equally likely possible final rounds.

Of these, $4\times 4 = 16$ of them end with $A$ missing their target and $B$ hitting theirs.

The probability of $B$ winning the game is then: $$\dfrac{16}{28} = \dfrac{4}{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer = 1/2

The game has to end by either A winning or B winning

Let's say A wins. He is just as likely to roll a 1 or a 2 on the last roll. Therefore in a game that A wins, probability of an even roll ending the game is 1/2, as 1(odd) and 2(even) are equally likely.

Let's say B wins. He is just as likely to roll a 3/4/5/6 on the last roll. Therefore in a game that B wins, probability of an even roll ending the game is 1/2, as 4 and 6 are favourable outcomes.

P.S. I have assumed that "ending on an even roll" as written in the title means the die outputs an even number. I agree that while the body of the question seems to suggest an even *turn*, this seems like the correct interpretation to me.

Comment: I agree with this completely (and just commented to that effect a minute ago).  Anyway, +1 but perhaps we are misreading the problem.

Comment: Yeah the title reads "ending on an even roll". The body says something different ig.

Comment: I suggest:  edit your post to indicate what interpretation you are using (i.e. "the probability of ending with the roll of an even digit").  After all, I really do think that that is the most natural interpretation of the question the way it is phrased.